# Windirstat shows Ubuntu is taking up 70 GB of space

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As a preface I am using Ubuntu with WSL.

I have been having trouble lately trying to figure out how exactly to clear disk space that is being taken up by a hard drive called `ext4.vhdx` stored in `CanonicalGroupLimitedUbuntu.../LocalState`.

Screenshot of Windirstat visualization:

[image: Screenshot of Windirstat visualization]

When I check Ubuntu to see how much storage is being used with `ncdu` it shows only 323.6 MB of storage are being used. However, when I run `df` it shows me a ton of filesystems that are taking up almost 99% of their allocated space.

Screenshot of `df` output:

[image: Screenshot of df output]

Are these filesystems what are causing my storage to be full and is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've shown with `df`, I would venture that `ncdu` is correct with the amount of consumed storage that is being used is correct. The number will be around 325MB, give or take. What you see in `df` are a number of mounts that point to the same location, which is why they all have the exact same set of numbers.

The issue that you face has nothing to do with Ubuntu and everything to do with Windows. There is [a long-standing WSL Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699) on this topic that has been open since November 2019. WSL will automatically grow your virtual disk, which you've correctly identified as `ext4.vhdx`, but shrinking it to reclaim unused space is something that must currently be done manually.

First things first:

1. Shut down the WSL machine:

   ```
   wsl --shutdown
   ```
2. Make a copy of the `vhdx` as a backup (in the event things go sideways)

Next, if you are using Windows Professional (or something more expensive), you can install Hyper-V and use Optimise-VHD to resize the image [as described in the above GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699):

```
optimize-vhd -Path .\ext4.vhdx -Mode full
```

If you are using Windows Home or above, you will need to [use `dispart`](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699#issuecomment-627133168) like this:

```
diskpart
select vdisk file="C:\WSL-Distros\…\ext4.vhdx"
attach vdisk readonly
compact vdisk
detach vdisk
exit
```

A third option would be to [export the WSL image and re-import it](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699#issuecomment-660104214), which can be done like this:

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl -l -v
wsl --export <DistroName> <PathToTarArchive>
wsl --unregister <DistroName>
wsl --import <DistroName> <PathToDistroNewDirectory> <PathToTarArchive>
wsl -l -v
```

***Note:** [The default username will need to be reset](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4276#issuecomment-553367389) after importing the image.*

As for "Why is Windows using 70.3GB of storage or a 0.3GB WSL image?", you will need to ask the people in Redmond, as knowing the answer is well beyond my pay grade.

Hope this helps you reclaim a good bit of storage.